# Check if node or Innernode equals text in Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

```
<button id="s:button" class="gui-button" type="submit" onclick="" name="s:button" role="button">
    <span class="btext gui-a">OK</span>
</button>
```

I want to check if the string 'OK' is in either the child nodes (for instance span) or button. I tried to submit the following XPath:

**//button[@type='submit']//child::text() = 'OK' or //text() ='OK'**

It works fine - but in Selenium I get a  **com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Command execution failure.- Command request: isElementPresent[xpath=//button[@type='submit']//child::text() = 'OK' or //text() ='OK', ] on session 7XXXX** . Is there a different XPath Syntax necessary.

Comment: this is sort of bad testing design.. the app should be consistent.  if it's the span that is going to have the text, then you can just use: (CSS) `button[type='submit'] > span.btext` no need to add the additional checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if text node of the button, or text node of button's child equals `"OK"` :

```
//button[@type='submit'][child::*/text()='OK' or text()='OK']
```

Note that `child::text()` refer to text node that is *direct child* of the button, your HTML sample doesn't have one of this type. To refer to text node that is *direct child* of a child node of the button use `child::*/text()` or simply `*/text()`.

You don't have to explicitly call `text()` actually, above XPath can be simplified further as follow :

```
//button[@type='submit'][*='OK' or .='OK']
```

Comment: thanks... but the X-Path result is Element='<button id="s:button" class="gui-button" type="submit" onclick="" name="s:button" role="button">
  <span class="btext gui-a">OK</span>
</button>'.... I rather need true or false to match or not match...

Comment: I'm afraid you can't achieve that using XPath only. You can execute this XPath, then using the host programming language check if the XPath return anything, if it is means `true` otherwise `false`